# WP_Query get the results weather selected or not

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with WP_Query to pull results from DB using multiple `taxonomy` from a custom post type.I have two taxonomy with drop down each.Taxonomy `city` and `cuisine` but if a dont't select any one of them results don't show.Actually i want to show results only with the key words even if these taxonomies are not selected.

### My codes

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        's' => get_query_var( 's' ),
        'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cuisine',    
                    'field' => 'slug',    
                    'terms' => $selected_cuisine,    
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'city',    
                    'field' => 'slug',    
                    'terms' => $selected_city,    
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                ),
            ),
    );

$restaurant_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

In what way does your query know when a taxonomy term is selected? You could try to add the `tax_query` with an `if` statement later on like this:

```
if ($term == 'cuisine') {
   $args['meta_query'][] = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'cuisine',    
     'field' => 'slug',    
     'terms' => $selected_cuisine,    
     'relation' => 'AND',
   );
 } elsif($term == 'city') {
   $args['meta_query'][] = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'city',    
     'field' => 'slug',    
     'terms' => $selected_city,    
     'relation' => 'AND',
   );
 }
```

This why the `tax_query` will only be added when the `term` is selected. I've had a few strange encounters with this issue in the past and this method fixed my issue quite a few times.